# How to invoke native call from Java to C++ dynamically?

Tags: java, android

In my Android app, my Java class has a static native method:

```
static native void myTest();
```

Things work as expected when I call this method from my Java code.

Now, for my specific needs, I would like not to declare this method stub in my Java code and still be able to call the native method dynamically. Is this possible?

My real goal is to defer loading of native library via `System.loadLibrary` until I have to invoke the method. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait as long as you want to call loadLibrary.  You can even do something like this:

```
private static boolean loaded = false;
private static native void nativeMyTest();
public static void myTest() {
  if(!loaded) {
    loaded = true;
    loadLibrary();
  }
  nativeMyTest();
}
```

Which will hide the native version unless you're loaded and only load at the first time you call the function.  But you can't call a function without a binding.